# How to reset rotation after onclick execution and make it possible to call it gain

Tags: javascript, onclick, image-rotation

I have a spinning arrows image. On click, it refreshes a captcha. I have it defined in a short css, with a rotation function called on click.
These are the CSS, the HTML and the Javascript:

```js
function rotatearrow() {
  arrowreload.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
  arrowreload.style.MozTransform  = 'rotate(360deg)';
  arrowreload.style.msTransform  = 'rotate(360deg)';
}

function reloadcaptcha() {
  //does what's needed and plays perfectly
}
```

```css
.reload {
  max-width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<img id="arrowreload" class="reload" src="../images/reload.png" onclick="rotatearrow(); reloadcaptcha();">
```

Now the point is: rotatearrow plays at the first click and rotate the arrows, but it never plays after the first time. What am I doing wrong? What changes I have to do to the code?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, we just need to keep incrementing the rotation value in multiples i.e -- 360,720,1080.....

```
function rotatearrow() {
    var transformValue = document.getElementById('arrowreload').style.webkitTransform;
    var transformInteger = transformValue ? ((transformValue.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)[0]/360)+1) : 1;
    document.getElementById('arrowreload').style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+(360*transformInteger)+'deg)';
}
```

Hope this is helpful, also this doesn't require external variable declaration...

Comment: It solves the issue. Only I have to manage three different functions for the three main browser syntax (webkitTransform, MozTransform, msTransform), since isn't in handy to write it all inside one

Comment: I think if we replace "webkitTransform" with "transform" we can accomplish this issue too...

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click you need to increment the degree:

```js
let degree = 0;
function rotatearrow() {
  degree += 360;
  arrowreload.style.webkitTransform = `rotate(${degree}deg)`;
}
```

```css
.reload {
      max-width: 32px;
      height: auto;
      transform: rotate(0);
      transition: all 0.8s;
 }
```

```html
<img id="arrowreload" class="reload" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/triangle-png-triangle-png-clipart-2400.png" onclick="rotatearrow();">
```

Comment: Very neat. It solves the issue. Also, I can make it cross-compatible with Mozilla and IE by simply adding two lines (one with MozTransform and one with msTransform).